# What am I missing on a Basic Angular 17 to get Routing for an SPA to work?

Tags: angular, routerlink

Why won't my 'routerLink' items navigation work?
It's a new project based on the only changes:

`ng new -S --routing home2`

## app.component.html

```
<div style="cursor: pointer;"><a routerLink="/page1" routerLinkActive>Page 1</a></div>&nbsp;
<div style="cursor: pointer;"><a routerLink="/page2" routerLinkActive>Page 2</a></div>&nbsp;

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

## app.routes.ts

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { Page1Component } from './components/page1/page1.component';
import { Page2Component } from './components/page2/page2.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'page1', component: Page1Component},
    {path: 'page2', component: Page2Component},
];
```

Comment: Can you show how you adding the route into `RouterModule`? Do you import `RouterModule` in your Angular application/module? Did you import `RouterModule` in your `AppComponent`?

Answer (score 1):

After running `ng new -S --routing home2`, angular just prepares an infrastructure for using router. You need then to add:

- router config (as you already did)
- router links if needed (as you already did)
- add missing imports (as Yong Shun already mentioned) in you app component, in your case you should add `RouterLink` and `RouterLinkActive` (or just `RouterModule` instead of three directives):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, RouterLink, RouterLinkActive],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.less'
})
```

after adding missing imports your routes should work

Also, you should pass one or several CSS classes to [routerLinkActive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive#description) directive.

For your future questions I would recommend to reproduce your issue using Angular project on [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/), this way it will be much easier for others to help you. GOOD LUCK with NG17 :)